# Array is not defined but can be console logged out

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am guessing this is some JS order or event thing? In the code below the hearts is being populated by a global context provider. The console.log works and the data type is an Array. However, the filter method errors out that hearts is not defined.

```
const [active, setActive] = useState();
const { hearts } = useContext(GlobalContext);
const record = props.record
console.log(hearts)
var arrayCheck = hearts.filter(heart => heart.id === record.id)
```

Any ideas? I would be hugely appreciative.

Comment: Write something like ```var arrayCheck = hearts && hearts.filter(heart => heart.id === record.id)```

Answer (score 2):

The console has this wonderful feature where it decides that it wants to show you what the value is currently rather than what it was at the time of logging (if there were mutations).

I'd recommend either making hearts have a default value of an empty array:

```
const { hearts = [] } = useContext(GlobalContext);
```

Or using

```
hearts?.filter()
```

so that you are taking care of the case where the hearts variable is undefined.